# A modifier which unions all input meshes in the stream

Tags: mesh, modifiers

Meshes may overlap if, for example, a modifier like `Array` produces overlapping elements or if an object consists simply of several meshes. The middle-row object is an example:
[image]

It looks identical to the object in the bottom row, where the two funnels have been merged with `Union`. However, the middle object gives problems to succeeding boolean operations, while the bottom one does not do that necessarily.

I can use the modfier `Union` `Self intersection` but that turns out to not always help, and also can be very slow up to making Blender unresponsive for a large number of polygons (reaction times of minutes).

There is also the modifier `Remesh` (example in the top row), but it produces a lot of triangles (again, performance problems with booleans) and decreases quality at the same time.

Any way of cleaning up such overlapping meshes, as in removing their internal walls?

Comment: There isn't general or all-in-one approach, if you search that powerful  Booleans and non-destructive workflow CAD apps would be more appropriate. For Blender, all the principles already settled down still apply: no overlapping faces with no shared vertices, no faces in the same place (z-fighting), no double verts, no flipped normals, enclosed / watertight mesh. For some cases with doubles / overlaps after Array Weld modifier can help. For others Remesh, then Decimate. For yet other ones, maybe another approach to model. Maybe show screenshots and file, it's too broad now.

Comment: I rephrased the question and gave an example. I guess that a trivial modifier which joins all the meshes in the modifier pipe (?)  using `Union` would do exactly what I asked for.